# Black screen after startx

Tags: ubuntu, startx

I want to use an old notebook as a "typewriter machine" with the only purpose to run ghostwriter, so I've installed Ubuntu (server) 18.04.4 LTS, x11 and ghostwriter itself. When I

`startx ghostwriter`, the screen stays black
same goes with
`startx chromium-browser` for having a comparison

The logfile Xorg.0.log doesn't show any errors but different warnings, like /usr/share/fonts/X11/[several folders] does not exist

Comment: I need a little bit more information - First of all it is recommended to use the full path of your command like `startx /usr/bin/chromium-browser` or /bin/chromium-browser
- Does switching the TTY solves the blackscreen? (For example: `Crtl + Alt + F3` and then back to your old TTY which may was F1 or F7 - depending on your configuration)

Comment: Thank you very much! Providing the full path solved my problem. Also thank you for the shortcuts, they're very useful. Since I couldn't close the question, I wanted to ask another. I want to open typora in full screen, but if I try ```startx /usr/bin/typora -geometry 1024x1200``` typora mistakenly takes the geometry params as the filename to open. To have a comparison ```chromium-browser --window-size=7000,7000 --start-fullscreen``` seems to work. It looks like these params are given to the application. But how to tell startx/xinit to open ***a window*** of agiven size?

Comment: (now i can comment). You simply pass the options to the command. If typora doesn't have something like -geometry this doesn't work (typora seems to expect a file path as first argument). If you want to run multiple programs at the same time, I would recommend using a window manager which handles this. Maybe you can define the geometry of the X Server but only as a whole, not for the specific windows if they not support the geometry natively.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am very glad you helped me. I wanted to keep it as simple as possible, but there seems to be no way without a Window Manager (at least for Typora). At least I have gotten it clarified now for best practice. Also without the Window Manager and pure ```startx``` I had **freezing issues**. I've installed ratpoison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the following methods in order to solve your problem:

1. Use full path of your command like `startx /usr/bin/chromium-browser` or /bin/chromium-browser (as recommended).
2. Switching the TTY could solve the blackscreen temporarily
   (For example: `Crtl + Alt + F3` and then back to your old TTY which may was F1 or F7 - depending on your configuration)